# MenuProviders are not switched automatically inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 2 Fragments. Each Fragment holds a MenuProvider which is added as follows:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MyMenuProvider1(), getViewLifecycleOwner());
}
```

But after opening the Activity containing the ViewPager I always see the menu of the second fragment, and switching fragments doesn't change anything. Looks like the MenuProvider of the second fragment is always overriding the first one. If I manage menu's in the old&deprecated way the menus are properly switched.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an automatic way to switch MenuProviders inside the ViewPager?

Comment: Just a guess but you may find that 'onViewCreated()' is not called each time you switch fragments as they are just created the once and kept in memory

Comment: @IvanWooll yes I know, I'm just wondering if there is an automatic way to switch Fragments Menus, instead of doing it manually, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73029662/12270122

Answer (score 1):

As an earlier comment suggested, your pager is optimizing by creating the two of its child fragments initially, and then persisting them in memory.
Instead of adding/removing your `MenuProvider` instances in child fragment `onViewCreated`, I recommend doing it in a `ViewPager` callback. You can add/remove when ViewPager changes pages. It would look something like the following:

```
class MyContainerFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager2 pager;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new UpdateMenuProviderOnPageChangeCallback());
    }

    class UpdateMenuProviderOnPageChangeCallback extends ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback {
        private MenuProvider provider1 = new MyMenuProvider1();
        private MenuProvider provider2 = new MyMenuProvider2();

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch(position) {
            case 1:
                requireActivity().removeMenuProvider(provider2);
                requireActivity().addMenuProvider(provider1, getLifecycleOwner());
                break;
            case 2:
                requireActivity().removeMenuProvider(provider1);
                requireActivity().addMenuProvider(provider2, getLifecycleOwner());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like an effective way to manage MenuProviders inside a ViewPager, but I was wondering if there is an automatic way for doing this, because if I use the deprecated mechanism to handle Menus, all is automatic and transparent.

Comment: Btw doesn't work very well in my case. I have Fragments that are used both inside a ViewPager and also alone inside a FragmentActivity... the containers shall be agnostic wrt Fragments Menus, only the Fragment itself should be responsible of its own menu.

Comment: @Carlo Codega In that case, this overload of `addMenuProvider` seems promising https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/MenuHost#addMenuProvider(androidx.core.view.MenuProvider,androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State). I'm thinking you would set the last argument to `Lifecycle.State.RESUMED` so that when your Fragment is swiped off-screen, activity would automatically remove its `MenuProvider`. You may need to call `requireActivity().invalidateMenu()` right after to make sure your Menu updates when providers change.

Comment: Fragments lifecycle state doesn't change when swiping from a ViewPager :(

Comment: @CarloCodega If you're using the old `ViewPager` then you can set your behavior to `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` so that the one that's scrolled-off goes back to the state `STARTED`.  https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter#FragmentStatePagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,int)

Comment: @CarloCodega If you're using `ViewPager2` then this should be the default behavior. Refer here if you're interested in migrating https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

Comment: It works when I use BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT as suggested by @OnurD.

Answer (score 1):

It's the least complicated to define `MenuProvider` in the `Activity`:

```
abstract public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Menu Provider */
    BaseMenuProvider mMenuProvider = null;

    /** It removes & adds {@link BaseMenuProvider} */
    public void setMenuProvider(BaseMenuProvider menuProvider) {
        if (mMenuProvider != null) {removeMenuProvider(mMenuProvider);}
        addMenuProvider(menuProvider, this, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
        mMenuProvider = menuProvider;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then change the `MenuProvider` from within `Fragment`:

```
BaseActivity activity = ((BaseActivity) this.requireActivity());
activity.setMenuProvider(new SettingsMenuProvider(activity));
```